# Twitter Authentications in C# web service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, twitter

Here is my scenario:

I have a mobile application, which will call a method in C# webservice, which will have 2 parameters, TwitterUsername and TwitterPassword.

Now in that web service method, I have to authenticate the user with these username and password for twitter and then there a further process to store the data (all four credentials - Consumerkey, ConsumerSecret, AccessToken & AccessTokenSecret) in one of the sql tables and the last identity generated has to be returned.

Can anyone please help me regarding twitter in webservice.. it would be a great help for me.

Thanks in advance,

Shailen

---

Ok, that I got from the your links provided. Now I have username, password, consumerkey and consumersecret in my webservice.

So, how can I get remaining two values for AccessToken and AccessTokenSecret without redirecting to any other page from webservice?

As, response.Redirect gives error in webservice.

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can authenticate users with a Username and Password anymore:

From Twitter:

> We announced in December of 2009 the deprecation of Basic Auth. Its
>   removal date from the platform is set for June 2010. We announced
>   towards the end of June 2010 that we have postponed this until August
>   16th 2010.

The only way to authenticate now is using oAuth:

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth/faq

Read this article for more info:

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/moving-from-basic-auth-to-oauth

> Basic Authentication is a liability. By storing logins and passwords,
>   a developer takes on additional responsibilities for the secure
>   storage of those credentials; the potential harm to users if login
>   credentials are leaked or abused is very high. Because many users
>   utilize the same password across many sites, the potential for damage
>   does not necessarily stop with their Twitter account.